# Why does the equation of a circle have to have the same $x^2,y^2$ coefficients?

Tags: geometry

In one of my geometry texts, it tells me they should be the same but not **why**. I am unsatisfied with this.

Suppose that:

$$ax^2+by^2 + cx + dy + f = 0 \text{ such that } a \neq b$$

is the equation of some circle. Upon completing the square and rearranging, I obtain

$$a\left(x+\frac{c}{2a}\right)^2 + b\left(y+\frac{d}{2b}\right)^2 = \frac{c^2}{4a} + \frac{d^2}{4b} - f$$

I know that a circle is defined as the set of points a fixed distance from a fixed point.

How can i arrive at a satisfying contradiction? At the moment I just can't see it.

Comment: If you know that a circle is defined as the set of points a fixed distance from a fixed point, then from the general form using centre $(p,q)$ and radius $r$, $$(x-p)^2 + (y-q)^2 = r^2$$which has the same $x^2$ and $y^2$ coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a\ne b$ and both of them are non-zero, then your equation above
$$\begin{align*}
a\left(x+\frac{c}{2a}\right)^2 + b\left(y+\frac{d}{2b}\right)^2 &= \frac{c^2}{4a} + \frac{d^2}{4b} - f\\
\left(x+\frac{c}{2a}\right)^2 + \frac ba\left(y+\frac{d}{2b}\right)^2 &= \frac{c^2}{4a^2} + \frac{d^2}{4ab} - \frac fa\\
\left(x+\frac{c}{2a}\right)^2 + \left(y\sqrt{\frac ba}+\frac{d}{2b}\sqrt\frac ba\right)^2 &= \frac{c^2}{4a^2} + \frac{d^2}{4ab} - \frac fa\\
\end{align*}$$
If $\frac ba > 0$, this means the equation only represents a circle in the scaled $\left(x,y\sqrt{\frac ba}\right)$ plane. In other words, the equation represents an ellipse.

If $\frac ba < 0$, this is not a circle either.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

****According to the definition of a circle , it's a locus of a points from a fixed point at a constant distant ****

*Now take a fixed point C( h,k)which we call it Center of circle and constant distance is 'r' which is it's radius*

Let $P(x,y)$ be any point in locus

By the definition we have

$PA=r$

*The distance between Center and a any locus point is constant 'r'*

$ \sqrt{(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2}=r$

*Squaring on both sides*

$ (x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$

$=>x^2+h^2-2xh+y^2+k^2-2yk=r^2$

$=>x^2+y^2-2hx-2ky+h^2+k^2-r^2=0$
*From
 this equation we have the following points which are characters of circle*

- circle is a second degree equation
- $coefficient of x^2=coefficient y^2$
- $coefficient of xy=0$
- $ radius of circle r>=0$

> Now compare your circle equation with this properties implies  a=b